# Pronunciation of Pommes Frites

Tags: pronunciation

When I first saw `Pommes Frites` I assumed the `es` would be pronounced, but it mostly seems like speakers say:

`pohm freet`

Rather than my initial assumption of something like:

`pohm-ez freet-z`

Why are the `es` on both words almost not pronounced?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Pommes Frites` is of French/Belgian origin and therefore pronounced (almost) as in French, with the typical German errors in speaking French. Germans pronounce either `/pɔm fʀɪts/` (this is more common) or `/pɔm fʀɪt/` (which is the correct French pronunciation).

Regional short forms are `Pommes` (pronounced `/pɔməs/`) and `Fritten` (`/fʀɪtn/`). In the short form

> Eine Portion Pommes¹.

the ~es is often emphasized. For entertainment purposes, you might google 'Imbißdeutsch at youtube', where you find a funny video about North German slang.

Comment: ~es is also not spoken by Germans who simply try to speak German without trying to speak French or even guessing, this were French.

Comment: @userunkown I added some pronounciation examples. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: mind googling youtube will not help

Comment: you still cannot google @ youtube ;)

Comment: ich bezog mich auf das benutzen des wortes "google". es geht darum dass nur bei google gegooglet(?) werden kann, bei youtube wird nur gesucht (obwohl es ja zu google gehört ;))

Comment: @Vogel612 Googeln hat inzwischen eine Bedeutung angenommen, die über die Benutzung der Suchmaschine gleichen Namens hinausgeht. Siehe Tempos.

Comment: @what die frage ist jetzt ob das im englischen genau so ist... wär mal ne Frage für EL&U

Comment: @Vogel: I see. `You might google 'Imbißdeutsch at youtube'`, not `You might google 'Imbißdeutsch' at youtube`. Corrected. I googled both terms (without 'at').

Comment: @what: Ich habe aber in der Tat gegoogelt, und zwar nach "Imbißdeutsch Youtube", nicht mit 'at' und mißverständlich nur das "Imbißdeutsch" vorgehoben. Mein Fehler.